# How to prevent asp mvc generating extra code on EditorForModel for every property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created an EditorTemplate for multiline text data types.

But after render page, ASP adds extra html code. How do I prevent this?

My EditorTemplate for multiline text is:

```
@model string
<div class="control-group">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x, new {@class="control-label col-md-2"})
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x , new { @class="form-control"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x, "", new { @class = "text-danger"    })
  </div>
</div>
```

generated code is:

```
<div class="editor-label">
   <label for="Description">ِDescription</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   /*Start My template*/
   <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Description">Description</label>
   <div class="col-md-10">
    <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id="Description" name="Description" rows="2"></textarea>
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
   </div>
   /*End of template*/
</div>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
```

Comment: Can you specify how exactly your custom editor template looks like

Comment: Which part of the generated HTML you do not want to be rendered? Is it the `cols` and `rows` attributes of the textarea?

Comment: i want only my template code rendered. i specify it in above!